# C++: "Prefer statically type-checked solutions (when applicable)"

Tags: c++, typechecking, static-typing

> Prefer statically type-checked solutions (when applicable).
>
> *(2013) Bjarne Stroustrup, The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition*

What does Stroustrup mean with this advice?

Comment: Is that it? Isn't there any text following it that explains this line?

Comment: I can guess at what this means, but SO's not in the business of guesses. Recommendation: Check out the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) It'll probably be in there along with explanation and code examples.

Comment: For example, [P.5: Prefer compile-time checking to run-time checking](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p5-prefer-compile-time-checking-to-run-time-checking)

Comment: I believe it means something along the lines of "if you're using `dynamic_cast`, you're doing it wrong. But also "stringly typed data is bad"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Prefer solutions that can be statically checked."

**Static checking:** the bug is found automatically before the program even runs.

**Dynamic checking:** the bug is found automatically when the code is executed.

See: [Static Checking (MIT Edu)](https://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa16/classes/01-static-checking/)

---

Compile-time checking (when and where possible) is always far better than run-time checking for clarity and performance reasons. You don't need to write error handlers for errors caught at compile time.

See: [P.5: Prefer compile-time checking to run-time checking](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p5-prefer-compile-time-checking-to-run-time-checking) ( Thanks to [@user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) )